# Is there a way to specify more than one app config file in one nunit project file?

Tags: nunit

I have a collection of unit test that I need to all run from one command line call. One of the assemblies uses a different config file than the rest of the assemblies. Is there a way to specify  more than one app config file in one nunit project file?

Answer (score 2):

Not in a project file, but you can specify a config file per assembly (e.g. TestAssembly1.dll.config)

Answer (score 1):

I would say when you script running your tests, you rename the right app.config to replace the other one so that when your tests start the right app.config is loaded. Let me know if you need an example of how to do that.